# PySimpleGUI - Loading Pop_Up for API call

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to make a pull request from an API and would like a small popup to appear and close after the API call is completed.

I tried the following code which does accomplish this, however the pop-up just appears as a black box without the Loading text present.  Is there some workaround for this to show the actual text/fully generate the popup while the API call is loading?

```
def popup(message):
    sg.theme('DarkGrey14')
    layout = [[sg.Text(message)]]
    window = sg.Window('Message', layout, no_titlebar=True, keep_on_top=True, finalize=True)
    return window

def get_completion(prompt):
            popup_win = popup('Loading...')
            try:
                #APICALL 
                popup_win.close()
            except:
                sg.popup_error('Error: Check your API parameters')
                popup_win.close()
            return response.choices[0].message.content
```

Comment: some GUIs wait for end of your function before they refresh/redraw content in window - this way they can refresh all change in one moment and window doesn't blink, bu tthis way you can't see changes during running function. Some GUIs may have also function to force system to refresh/redraw it at once. For example `Tkinter` has `root.update()` - but I don't know if `PySimpleGUI` has similar function.

Comment: I found that `PySimpleGUI` has `window.refresh()`

Comment: You need to call method `read` before you close it, or the window will be closed immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple demo code for you ...

```py
from time import sleep
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def load():
    sleep(5)

win = sg.Window('Title', [[sg.Text("Loading .....")]], no_titlebar=True, finalize=True)
win.perform_long_operation(load, "Done")
win.read(close=True)

sg.Window('Title', [[sg.Text("Main Window"), sg.Button('Exit')]]).read(close=True)
```

Another complex one

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Popup(sg.Window):

    def __init__(self, main_window, message, theme="LightBlue3"):
        self.main = main_window
        self.message = message
        sg.theme(theme)
        layout = [[sg.Text(message, key="Message")]]
        super().__init__('Title', layout, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True,
            keep_on_top=True, element_padding=(0, 0), margins=(0, 0),
            finalize=True)
        self.x0, self.y0 = self.main.current_location(more_accurate=True)
        w0, h0 = self.main.current_size_accurate()
        w1, h1 = self.current_size_accurate()
        self.x1, self.y1 = self.x0+(w0-w1)//2, self.y0+(h0-h1)//2
        self.refresh()
        self.move(self.x1, self.y1)
        self.bind("<Configure>", 'Configure')

    def configure(self):
        x11, y11 = popup.current_location(more_accurate=True)
        x00, y00 = window.current_location(more_accurate=True)
        if (x11, y11) != (self.x1, self.y1):
            self.x0, self.y0 = self.x0+x11-self.x1, self.y0+y11-self.y1
            self.main.move(self.x0, self.y0)
            self.x1, self.y1 = x11, y11
        elif (x00, y00) != (self.x0, self.y0):
            self.x1, self.y1 = self.x1+x00-self.x0, self.y1+y00-self.y0
            popup.move(self.x1, self.y1)
            self.x0, self.y0 = x00, y00
        self.main.force_focus()

def download():
    steps = 10
    window.write_event_value("Step", (0, steps))
    for step in range(steps):
        sleep(0.5)
        window.write_event_value("Step", (step+1, steps))
    sleep(0.5)

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12, "bold"))
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Load all data")],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Text("", justification="center", expand_x=True, key="Status")],
    [sg.Button("Load", key="LOAD"), sg.Button("Exit")],
]
window = sg.Window('File Download Tool', layout, size=(320, 240),
    element_justification='center', enable_close_attempted_event=True,
    grab_anywhere=True, finalize=True)
window.bind("<Configure>", 'Configure')
popup = None

while True:

    win, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "Exit") and popup is None:
        break

    elif event == 'LOAD' and popup is None:
        popup = Popup(window, "Loading ...")
        window.perform_long_operation(download, "Done")

    elif event == 'Configure':
        if popup:
            popup.configure()

    elif event == "Step":
        step, steps = values[event]
        window["Status"].update(f"{step:0>2d}/{steps}")

    elif event == "Done":
        popup.close()
        popup = None
        window["Status"].update(f"Done")

window.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone in the comments, the window.refresh() and window.read() solutions both worked perfectly.  Updated functional code below for anyone else that stumbles upon this

```py
def popup(message):
    sg.theme('DarkGrey14')
    layout = [[sg.Text(message)]]
    window = sg.Window('Message', layout, no_titlebar=True, keep_on_top=True, finalize=True)
    return window

def get_completion(prompt):
    popup_win = popup('Loading...')
    popup_win.refresh()
    try:
        #APICALL
        popup_win.close()
    except:
        sg.popup_error('Error: Check your API parameters')
        popup_win.close()
    return response.choices[0].message.content
```